# The write to the table has become longer after Multi threading

Tags: python, sql, multithreading, pandas, odbc

I am using multi threading to write data into a SQL table. Even after using multiple threads(10) the process of writing has become slower. The writing process has become slower than what it was when I was trying to do it in a single thread. I am trying to bring down the write time to milliseconds. The result of the writing become slower is that the data cannot be used by the next process for further processing.
The write time goes up to a few seconds. I am trying to do multiple writes into the database. My dataframe gets updated every 250ms.

```
import threading 
import pandas as pd
from ib_insync import *
util.startLoop()
import datetime
import urllib.request
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pyodbc
import numpy
from queue import Queue
import time
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
##Connections to Database
engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % params, echo=False,fast_executemany = True) #set echo = True to print all sql statements sent to server
conn = engine.connect()
ib = IB()
ib.connect('127.0.0.1', 4002, clientId=4)
symbolList =  pd.read_csv('st2018_symbols.csv')
symbolList = symbolList['RIC'].str.split('.',expand = True)[0].tolist()
symbolList = set(symbolList)
contracts = [Stock(symbol ,'SMART', 'USD') for symbol in symbolList]
ib.qualifyContracts(*contracts)

## Requesting Market Data  
for contract in contracts:
    ib.reqMktData(contract, '', False, False)

## Function to store the incoming ticks in a DataFrame and write that DataFrame to SQL table
def onPendingTickers(tickers):
    global df,df1,df2,df3,df4,df5,q
    for t in tickers:
        df.loc[t.contract.symbol] = (t.contract.symbol,
             t.bid,t.bidSize,t.ask,t.askSize,t.last,t.volume,t.time)    
#        clear_output(wait=True)
    df1['SystemTime'] = pd.Series([datetime.datetime.now()] * len(df),index = [c.symbol for c in contracts])                

    df2 = pd.concat([df,df1],axis = 1)
    df2['SystemTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['SystemTime'])
    df2.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    q.put(df2)

#    print(q.queue,'df2')
def write_toDB(conn):
    global df,df1,df2,df3,df4,df5,q

    while True:
        df2 = q.get()
#        print(df2,'df2')
        start = datetime.datetime.now()
        if len(df3) > 0:
            df4 =  df2[(df2['bid'].values <= df2['ask'].values) & (0.75*df3['bid'].values <= df2['bid'].values)  & (df2['bid']<= 1.25*df3['bid'].values) & (0.75*df3['ask'].values <= df2['ask'].values) & (df2['ask'] <= 1.25*df3['ask'].values)]    
            df4 = df4.dropna(how = 'any')
#            print(df4,'df4')  
            df4.to_sql('testTick',conn,if_exists = 'append',index= False,method = 'multi',chunksize = 230)       
    #        df2.to_csv('tickData.csv',header=False,index = False,mode = 'a' )
        else:
            df5 = df2.dropna(how = 'any')
            df5.to_sql('testTick',conn,if_exists = 'append',index= False,method = 'multi',chunksize = 230) 
#            print(df5,'df5')      
        df3 = df2
#        q1.put(df3)
        print('time diff',datetime.datetime.now() - start) 
        q.task_done()

def write_toMB():
    global df3
#    while True:
#        df3 = q1.get()

    start = datetime.datetime.now()
#    print(df3)
    cursor1.execute(''' TRUNCATE TABLE dariush.dbo.MB''')
    cnxn1.commit()
    df3.to_sql('MB',conn11,if_exists = 'append',index= False,method = 'multi',chunksize = 230) 
    print("Write time",datetime.datetime.now()-start)


if __name__ == "__main__": 
    # creating thread 
    q = Queue()
    ib.pendingTickersEvent += onPendingTickers

    workers = 10
    thread_list = []
    for i in range(workers):
        t = threading.Thread(target=write_toDB,args = [conn[i],])
        t.start()
        thread_list.append(t)


     ## Timer to keep the connection open to IB for inflow of data
    ib.sleep(23400)
    ib.pendingTickersEvent -= onPendingTickers
    ib.disconnect()
    for thread in thread_list:
        thread.join()
    print("Done!")
```

Comment: How much slower in comparison? Starting multiple threads takes processing time and therefore there is a trade off where doing it is not worth it in some cases (or if your test case is small compared to a large use case).

Comment: Any chance of reducing that to a [mcve]? With emphasis on minimal.

Comment: The write time goes up to a few seconds. I am trying to do multiple writes into the database. My dataframe gets updated every 250ms.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of multiple threads, have you tried separate client instances for each symbol? IB allows 32 different client IDs.